Autostart not working for Flutter-App (Android)
Is there a way to make my app start when the Android phone is started? I already tried all the available packages (for example this) for this on several phones but nothing happened (the autostart settings should appear).
It would be really great if anyone could help me!
Best regards
Dennis
I even tried a solution without package, but it did not work either: see here

This isn't a Flutter specific problem. You should find out how to make any app autostart on Android

And how do I achieve this? And what about available packages like https://pub.dev/packages/auto_start_flutter?

Seems it gets the user to the needed permission screen, but you probably need more to make the app auto_starr

It does not even get me to the permission screen. But what else do I need?
